# Combine two one-way streams into a two-way stream

Tags: c#, sockets, compression

In particular I am using a `Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream` to do Zlib compression on a `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream`.

Problem is, `ZlibStream` is a one-way stream; you can `Read()` or `Write()` but not both. You need two separate streams, one for sending and one for receiving (one compressing and the other decompressing). Which works fine until you need to pass it to functions that are expecting a single two-way stream (both `Read()` and `Write()` functionality). For example, `new System.Net.Security.SslStream(Stream base)`.

I realize I can write a `Stream` class that takes a writing-stream and a reading-stream and calls the correct stream in the overrides. But I was hoping this already exists in the framework somewhere or there was an implementation already available.

Comment: But you should always compress _before_ encryption, no? The problem shouldn't arise.

Comment: @Henk, that is just an example. The actual stream that will encapsulate this one is a proprietary XMPPStream, of which will be must more difficult to give a meaningful example of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no class that will do this for you.  However, the wrapper class you'll need to write is simple and shouldn't take you very long at all.

You will probably inherit from *Stream*, but if you analyze your needs and the other available stream types, you may find that inheriting from a more specific class will help you out.

**Edit**: Due to Lucas B's comments.

Please keep in mind that normal uses of *Stream* objects require that they actually inherit from *Stream*.  Otherwise, you can't pass it as a parameter to a large number functions that expect a stream.

Comment: What was the downvote for?  If I'm wrong about the availability of a class to do this, why isn't there an answer that tells us what it is?

Comment: @NickWhaley:  I know that. :)   Can you tell me who downvoted? :P

Answer (score 4):

Easy enough if it does not already exist in the framework.

```
    public class StreamRWJoin : Stream {
        public Stream WriteStream { get; set; }
        public Stream ReadStream { get; set; }
        private bool leaveOpen;

        public StreamRWJoin(Stream readfrom, Stream writeto, bool leaveOpen = false) {
            WriteStream = writeto; ReadStream = readfrom;
            this.leaveOpen = leaveOpen;
        }

        public override bool CanRead {
            get { return ReadStream.CanRead; }
        }

        public override bool CanSeek {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanWrite {
            get { return WriteStream.CanWrite; }
        }

        public override void Flush() {
            WriteStream.Flush();
        }

        public override long Length {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override long Position {
            get {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
            return ReadStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
            WriteStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        public override void Close() {
            if (!leaveOpen)
                try {
                    WriteStream.Close();
                } finally {
                    ReadStream.Close();
                }
        }

        public override IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state) {
            return ReadStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);
        }
        public override int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) {
            return ReadStream.EndRead(asyncResult);
        }

        public override IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state) {
            return WriteStream.BeginWrite(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);
        }
        public override void EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) {
            WriteStream.EndWrite(asyncResult);
        }

        public override int ReadByte() {
            return ReadStream.ReadByte();
        }
        public override void WriteByte(byte value) {
            ReadStream.WriteByte(value);
        }

        public override int ReadTimeout {
            get {
                return ReadStream.ReadTimeout;
            }
            set {
                ReadStream.ReadTimeout = value;
            }
        }

        public override int WriteTimeout {
            get {
                return WriteStream.WriteTimeout;
            }
            set {
                WriteStream.WriteTimeout = value;
            }
        }

        public override bool CanTimeout {
            get {
                return ReadStream.CanTimeout || WriteStream.CanTimeout;
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return ReadStream.GetHashCode() ^ WriteStream.GetHashCode();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (disposing && !leaveOpen) {
                try {
                    ReadStream.Dispose();
                } finally {
                    WriteStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return "Read: " + ReadStream.ToString() + ", Write: " + WriteStream.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any idea how to do seeking then? I'm trying to handle an archive and zip files also require seek.